# How can I get country's timezone?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I want to get the country's timezone to prevent a user to change his time to be able to use my application. Now, I set my application's opening hours between 8AM to 5PM. When a user change his time to the opening hours even if it is not yet the time in his country, the user cannot proceed to the restaurant fragment but I don't have any idea how do it. I have searched Google yet didn't find any solutions. I hope someone can help me.

This is my current code:

```
val tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8")
    val c = Calendar.getInstance(tz)
    val mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    val mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if (mHour >= 8 && mHour <= 17) {

        viewModel.getMessageError().observe(this, Observer {
            Toast.makeText(context, it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })

        viewModel.getRestaurantList().observe(this, Observer {
            dialog.dismiss()
            adapter = MyRestaurantAdapter(requireContext(), it)
            recycler_restaurant!!.adapter = adapter
            recycler_restaurant!!.layoutAnimation = layoutAnimationCotroller
        })
    }
    else {
        dialog.dismiss()
        Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "Shop is closed. We're open between 8AM to 5PM",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to get Calendar with local timezone. So you can do this by removing parameter.

```
 val c = Calendar.getInstance()
```